DTOs and Single-responsibility principle
I'm developing a PHP application and trying to understand DTOs in context of single-responsibility principle. Being more specific, is it a bad practice having helper methods like toArray(), getValue(), etc. built in DTOs?
Wikipedia tells that:

The difference between data transfer objects and business objects or
data access objects is that a DTO does not have any behavior except
for storage, retrieval, serialization and deserialization of its own
data (mutators, accessors, serializers and parsers).

So from my point of view I don't break single-responsibility principle, but I don't know for sure so I would appreciate any help and opinion.

This question treats your understanding of SRP as a (correct) constant and judges other things in the light of it. It might be better to instead revisit your understanding of SRP, because it's (directly) unrelated to the nature of a DTO, let alone the specific points you raise what should/n't be done with DTOs due to SRP.

It seems to me that toArray() and getValue() fall under the "retrieval" exception (possibly also "federalization") given in Wikipedia, so I'm a little puzzled as to why you've asked this question.  Have I missed something?

Oops, autocorrect said "federalization" when I typed "deserialization"!

The Single Responsibility Principle does not tell to do only one thing. It says there should be only one reason to change. In your case, the reason to change is the structure of the data to transfer, e.g. needing to add or remove related / nested data in the DTO.
From this viewpoint, toArray() and getValue() seem perfectly acceptable. They help to ensure that the responsibilty stays manageable by breaking it down into smaller functional blocks. The reason to change still remains the structure of the data.
P.S: by the way, there are other definitions for DTO objects. Martin Fowler's for example.

The chef in the restaurant kitchen has one responsibility: To cook. He doesn't do the payroll, tell the waiters what to do etc., that's not his responsibility. But cookink steaks, sausages, pasta, vegetables, fish, that's all within his one responsibility. Same here. If I need the data of a DTO as an array, then toArray() is part of the one responsibility of the DTO.

what if you need to move that chef from one restaurant to another though? He wouldn't  need to "cook" on the way, and taxis are expensive, you would only send the raw chef, not any extra bits like his hat

@Ewan if you send only the cook, once arrived, he/she will probably use the same techniques and practices he/she already knows and go along with cook responsibly. He/she will offer the same cook interface, including cutting carrot in small pieces. And will consume the same tools, even if from a different brand, using their known interface.

A Chef does far more than cook.  Or they’d just be a Cook. I wouldn’t be surprised to find a Chef managing cooks, ordering food, or paying for advertising. I would be surprised to find them doing the plumbing.

Ahh but he might be a MikeRowRestaurant.Chef in the first place and a JavaBucksRestaurant.Chef in the second. with similar but different skills. If he just when from one MikeRow kitchen to another he would probably use some fancy car provided by Mike

The chef might be responsible for payroll if they also happen to be the owner of the business, and might also be responsible for serving the food to customers too - maybe the business can't afford a separate waiter or someone to sort out the payroll, so maybe the chef is the only person who can do it.     All of this is to say that the decision on whether something has "too many responsibilities" depends entirely on context,  and why it often is not a problem at all for a class to be doing quite a lot of different things -- sometimes splitting things out is just "YAGNI".

Your chef example demonstrates mainly one thing: that such comparisons have narrow limits and become easily absurd beyond those limits ;-)
